# CTE Recursive Query getting Child Ancestors based on Child as parameter (bottom-up)

Tags: sql-server, recursion, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I have a Hierarchy Table. What I want to do is to retrieve the table hierarchy based on **AgentID** as a parameter.so the return result should be in descending order. Most sample I found on the net just show how to retrieve the hierarchy table based on parent as parameter.

Below is the closest sample that I can use to retrieve **Child/Parent/Parent.... hierarchy**.
But how can I use AgentID as a parameter to get the bottom-up hierarchy?

```
    ;WITH rCTE AS 
     (
        SELECT  AgentID ,
        RootID ,
        CAST(AgentID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathIDs,
        CAST(AgentName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathText,
        CAST(IntroducerID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))  AS PathCost
FROM TblHierarchy r WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TblHierarchy n WHERE r.AgentID = n.RootID ) 
UNION ALL
SELECT  n.AgentID ,
        n.RootID ,
        r.PathIDs  + '>' + CAST(n.AgentID AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS PathIDs,
        r.PathText + '>' + n.AgentName AS PathText,
        r.PathCost  + CAST(n.IntroducerID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathCost
FROM rCTE r
INNER JOIN dbo.TblHierarchy n ON r.RootID = n.AgentID 



   )
    SELECT  PathIDs ,
            PathText ,
            PathCost     
             FROM rCTE r
      WHERE r.RootID =0--IS NULL 
      ORDER BY PathCost

   option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Table sample ;

```
      CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblHierarchy](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NULL,
    [AgentName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RootID] [int] NULL,
    [IntroducerID] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data sample :

```
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Toh', 0, 0, N'', NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (2, 2, N'Man', 1, 1, N'Child of Toh', NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (3, 3, N'Rul', 1, 1, N'Child of Toh', NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (4, 4, N'Rafiq', 2, 2, N'Child of Man', NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (5, 5, N'Paan', 2, 2, N'Child of Man', NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (7857, 6, N'TohChild0', 3, 1, NULL, NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (7858, 7, N'TohChild1', 3, 1, NULL, NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (7859, 8, N'TohChild2', 4, 1, NULL, NULL)
     INSERT [dbo].[TblHierarchy] ([ID], [AgentID], [AgentName], [RootID], [IntroducerID], [Description], [HierarchyTree]) VALUES (7860, 9, N'TohChild3', 4, 1, NULL, NULL)
```

This is the current result of this CTE query

```
    255>127>63>31>15>7>3>1
    254>127>63>31>15>7>3>1
    253>126>63>31>15>7>3>1
```

The result is like what I want,but this one is too generic. how can I get a result like this by using **AgentID** as a **parameter**. So, the result will only return a single row.

**EDIT**

RootID is the Parent and AgentID is the Child..I want to get a bottom-up hierarchy, means all the parent for a particular AgentID

Let say the **AgentID = 327**
So,my expected result will be **327>163>81>40>20>10>5>2>1**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `ChildID` in your SQL: which column defines the hierarchy?

Comment: RootID is the Parent and AgentID is the Child..I want to get a bottom-up hierarchy, means all the parent for a particular AgentID

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Please update the question with that information through out (and also I would suggest changing the inserts into a table showing the data): make the question as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: Just a single row..Means,I can pass the AgentID as parameter and get the bottom-up hierarchy for that particular AgentID

Comment: I have updated the question.. can I use the AgentID as a parameter to get its root?

Comment: Just add to the WHERE clause in your first statement in your recursive CTE to have something like `WHERE agendid = 327`. That first statement is the "Recursive Seed" which starts the recursion.

Comment: Your column HierarchyTree is superfluous and should be removed.

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit confusing. Actually i want to get all the ancestors for the agentid.so,how can i use the agentid as the paramater to search it roots? Eg; AgentID =327. So that the query will return this result , 327>163>81>40>20>10>5>2>1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE has two parts:

1. The recursive seed. This is the first query above the union wherein you set up the starting point for the iterations. The starting point you have is to select any `agentid` that is not a `rootid`
2. The recursive term. This is the query that is called over and over again until the join condition fails, signalling the end of the recursion for that particular branch.

Since you want to get only the results for a particular `agentid` instead of - any `agentid` that is not a `rootid` - like you currently have, then change the `WHERE` clause on that recursive seed:

```
WITH rCTE
AS (
    SELECT AgentID,
        RootID,
        CAST(AgentID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathIDs,
        CAST(AgentName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathText,
        CAST(IntroducerID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathCost
    FROM TblHierarchy r
    WHERE AgentID = 327

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n.AgentID,
        n.RootID,
        r.PathIDs + '>' + CAST(n.AgentID AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS PathIDs,
        r.PathText + '>' + n.AgentName AS PathText,
        r.PathCost + CAST(n.IntroducerID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathCost
    FROM rCTE r
    INNER JOIN dbo.TblHierarchy n ON r.RootID = n.AgentID
    )
SELECT PathIDs,
    PathText,
    PathCost
FROM rCTE r
WHERE r.RootID = 0 --IS NULL
```

As a second option you could also change the SELECT statement that selects from the recursive CTE to `WHERE rootID = 0 AND pathIDs like '327%'`